# JSON omitempty omitting non-empty values

Tags: go

I have this struct:

```
type Proxy struct {
    Ip string
    Port string
    Username string `json:"group,omitempty" bson:",omitempty"`
    Password string `json:"group,omitempty" bson:",omitempty"`
}
```

`Username` and `Password` values are assigned (but they can be nil or empty, thats why i want to omit them in such case).

```
    proxy := &Proxy{}

    proxy.Ip = "1.1.1.1";
    proxy.Port = "1111";
    proxy.Username = "user";
    proxy.Password = "pass";
```

However they are omitted in `json` output:

```
    json, err := json.Marshal(proxy)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(str))
```

the `log.Println(string(str))` output is following:

```
{"Ip":"1.1.1.1","Port":"1111"}
```

What could be the reason for them to be missing in JSON output?

Comment: `Username` and `Password` are both assigned the JSON field name `group`, which is invalid. Also just to note you state "they can be nil or empty", but `string` cannot be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a struct tags repeated - linter go-vet message in the example https://play.golang.org/p/Um5M1R4DZ49 . Once you place unique values (like `user` and `pass`) everything will work

This is correct (not duplicated struct tags)

```
Username string `json:"user,omitempty" bson:",omitempty"`
Password string `json:"pass,omitempty" bson:",omitempty"`
```